# Differentiate this expression

Tags: calculus

This seemed fairly simple to me, but I'm doing it wrong. I have to differentiate p with respect to T, a and b and R are constants.

$$p = \frac{2a}{b^2} e^{0.5-\frac{a}{RTb}} - \frac{RT}{b}e^{0.5-\frac{a}{RTb}}$$

I tried to calculate this and got

$$\frac{dp}{dT} = \frac{2a^2}{RTb^3}e^{0.5-\frac{a}{RTb}} - \frac{R}{b}e^{0.5-\frac{a}{RTb}} - \frac{aRT}{RTb^2}e^{0.5-\frac{a}{RTb}}$$

That was just from the product rule. Apparently though, I should get a quadratic in T. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Notice that in the exponent you have a function of $T$, and therefore need to apply the chain rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that

$$\left(\frac1T\right)'=-\frac1{T^2}$$

so you're mainly missing the squared $\;T\;$ in the denominator in both cases (in the rightmost one the square gets cancelled:

$$\frac{d}{dT}\left(e^{\frac12-\frac1{RTb}}\left[\frac{2a}{b^2}-\frac{RT}b\right]\right)=\frac1{RbT^2}e^{\frac12-\frac1{RTb}}\left(\frac{2a}{b^2}-\frac{RT}b\right)-\frac Rbe^{\frac12-\frac a{RBT}}=$$

$$=\frac{e^{\frac12-\frac a{RTb}}}b\left(\frac{2a}{Rb^2T^2}-\frac1{bT}-\frac Rb\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $e^{0.5-\frac{a}{RTb}}$,
$$\frac{d}{dT}e^{0.5-\frac{a}{RTb}}=e^{0.5-\frac{a}{RTb}}(-\frac{a}{Rb})\frac{d}{dT}(\frac{1}{T})=\frac{a}{RT^2b}e^{0.5-\frac{a}{RTb}}$$